# extract NSDecimalNumber from String with characters in it

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, decimal

in an ios app, I have a string that starts with letters, followed by a decimal number.

Example: `tafas12.53`

I need a way (maybe by using regular expressions?) to extract the decimal number

something like:

```
 NSDecimalNumber num = [self extractNumber:myString];

- (NSDecimalNumber *) extractNumber:(NSString*)string
{
     //extract it and return it
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
- (NSDecimalNumber *) extractNumber:(NSString*)string
{
     NSString *numberString = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]];
     return [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithDouble:[numberString doubleValue]];
}
```

Comment: I have a personal aversion to regex.  If this doesn't work for you, I would go character by character and just parse out your numerical substring by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below regex to get the match the decimal number present in the input string,

```
\d+\.\d+
```

Use a capturing group to capture the decimal number.

```
.*(\d+\.\d+).*
```